# Computing variance of compound Poisson process from the M.G.F.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, poisson-distribution, moment-generating-functions, poisson-process

> Let $X_t = \sum_{i=1}^{N_t} Y_i$ and $N_t$ be a Poisson process with
>   intensity $\lambda >0$. Suppose $Y_i$ are i.i.d. (independent of
>   $N_t$) with normal distribution $N(m,\sigma^2)$. Compute $Var(X_t)$.

The MGF of $X_t$ is:

$\psi_{X_t}(u) = e^{\lambda t (\psi_Y(u) -1)}$

Then,

$\dfrac{d}{du}\psi_{X_t}(u) = \lambda t \dfrac{d}{du}\psi_{Y}(u) e^{\lambda t (\psi_Y(u) -1)}$

And,

$\dfrac{d^2}{du^2}\psi_{X_t}(u) = (\lambda t)^2 (\dfrac{d}{du}\psi_{Y}(u))^2 + \lambda t \dfrac{d^2}{du^2}\psi_{Y}(u) e^{\lambda t (\psi_Y(u) -1)}$

So,

$E(X_t^2) = \dfrac{d^2}{du^2}\psi_{X_t}(u) |_{u=0} = (\lambda t)^2 m^2 + \lambda t \sigma ^2 $

$=>Var(X_t) = (\lambda t)^2 m^2 + \lambda t \sigma ^2  - (\lambda t m)^2 = \lambda t \sigma ^2 $

But on wikipedia they have: $\lambda t m^2 + \lambda t \sigma ^2 $

**Why is my answer not identical to wikipedia? They use a different method so I cannot track my error.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_process

Comment: The n-th derivative of the moment generating function of $X$ at $0$ gives $E[X^n]$, i.e. the moments, not the central moments in general. And $X_t$ is not zero mean, so they don't coincide.

Comment: @Batman Ok. So then I have $E[X_t^2] =(\lambda t)^2 m^2 + (\lambda t) \sigma ^2$. Then, $Var(X_t) = E[X_t^2]  - (E[X_t])^2 = (\lambda t)^2 m^2 + (\lambda t) \sigma ^2 - (\lambda t m)^2 = \lambda t \sigma ^2$. But wikipedia has $\lambda t (\sigma ^2 +m^2)$ ? !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the law of total variance,
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Var}(X(t)) &= \mathbb E[\mathrm{Var}(X(t))\mid N(t)] + \mathrm{Var}(\mathbb E[X(t)\mid N(t)])\\
&= \mathbb E[N(t)\mathrm{Var}(Y_1)] + \mathrm{Var}(N(t)\mathbb E[Y_1])\\
&= \sigma^2\mathbb E[N(t)] + m^2\mathrm{Var}(N(t))\\
&= \sigma^2\lambda t+ m^2\lambda t\\
&= (\sigma^2 + m^2)\lambda t.
\end{align}
The MGF of $X(t)$ is 
$$\varphi_{X(t)}(s)=e^{\lambda t\left(\varphi_{Y_1}(s)-1\right)} $$
where $$\varphi_{Y_1}(s) = e^{ms + \frac12\sigma^2s^2}.$$
We have
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf ds}\varphi_{Y_1}(s)&=\left(m+s \sigma^2\right) e^{ms+\frac12\sigma^2 s^2},\\
\frac{\mathsf d^2}{\mathsf d^2s}\varphi_{Y_1}(s)&=\sigma ^2 e^{ms+\frac12\sigma^2 s^2}+\left(m+s \sigma ^2\right)^2 e^{ms+\frac12\sigma^2 s^2},
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Y_1]&=\varphi_{Y_1}'(0)=m\\
\mathbb E[Y_1^2]&=\varphi_{Y_1}''(0)=m^2+\sigma^2. \\
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf ds}\varphi_{X(t)}(s)&=\lambda t\varphi_{Y_1}'(s) e^{\lambda t\left(\varphi_{Y_1}(s)-1\right)} \\
\frac{\mathsf d^2}{\mathsf d^2s}\varphi_{X(t)}(s)&= \lambda t\left(\lambda t\varphi_{Y_1}'(s)^2 + \varphi_{Y_1}''(s)\right)e^{\lambda t\left(\varphi_{Y_1}(s)-1\right)}
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X(t)]&=\varphi_{X(t)}'(0)=\lambda tm  \\
\mathbb E[X(t)^2]&=\varphi_{X(t)}''(0)= \lambda t(\lambda tm^2+m^2+\sigma^2). \\
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(X(t)) &= E[X(t)^2] - E[X(t)]^2\\
&= \lambda t(\lambda tm^2+m^2+\sigma^2) - \lambda^2 t^2 m^2\\
&= \lambda t(\lambda tm^2+m^2+\sigma^2 - \lambda t m^2)\\
&= \lambda t(m^2+\sigma^2).
\end{align}

Comment: why does my method using the MGF not agree? I am missing the $m^2$.

Comment: You use the same method as wikipedia. But the point of my question was to determine why the MGF method is not agreeing!

Comment: @Pii You don't have the right expression for $\mathbb E[X(t)^2]$ - see edit.